# Overlays with GoogleMaps on Monodroid

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.android, overlays

I have problems implementing the ItemizedOverlay on monodroid from this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html, Does someone knows how to do that on Monodroid?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin's [Maps and Location](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Maps_and_Location#Adding_Itemized_Overlays) tutorial covers how to create map overlays. ItemizedOverlay is an abstract class, so you need to create your own subclass of it.